# Why Microsoft login page is not opening in my Corporate App Service but opening in my personal account's App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have added a button in login page so that user can log into website through Microsoft account as well, This is the link of page where user is directed-to, after clicking on button, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/`. It is working fine when I am hosting application in IIS and even opens the Microsoft login page when I host it on App Service of my personal account. But the login page of Microsoft( [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/) ) is not opening when I am hosting the same application in the App Service of my Corporate Azure Account. I understand that it is the access issue but I don't understand how can I get it fixed. I need to specify the steps to my IT help department in order to make the required changes.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you have Identity Provider added in the Deployed Azure Web App ? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b8Tw.png)